# JPA: N+1 query even after FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've read a few articles that shows how to solve n+1 query problem in JPA, but none of it worked for me.

When I try to fetch the data, JPA makes n+1 queries.

```
select owner0_.id as id1_1_, owner0_.created_at as created_2_1_, owner0_.updated_at as updated_3_1_, owner0_.name as name4_1_, owner0_.version as version5_1_ from owner owner0_

select cars0_.owner_id as owner_id6_0_0_, cars0_.id as id1_0_0_, cars0_.id as id1_0_1_, cars0_.created_at as created_2_0_1_, cars0_.updated_at as updated_3_0_1_, cars0_.license_no as license_4_0_1_, cars0_.owner_id as owner_id6_0_1_, cars0_.version as version5_0_1_ from car cars0_ where cars0_.owner_id=? [1]

select cars0_.owner_id as owner_id6_0_0_, cars0_.id as id1_0_0_, cars0_.id as id1_0_1_, cars0_.created_at as created_2_0_1_, cars0_.updated_at as updated_3_0_1_, cars0_.license_no as license_4_0_1_, cars0_.owner_id as owner_id6_0_1_, cars0_.version as version5_0_1_ from car cars0_ where cars0_.owner_id=? [2]
```

Below is the code snippet :

```
@Entity
public class Owner extends BaseEntity implements EntityTransformer<OwnerDto> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Car> cars;

    @Override
    public OwnerDto convertToDto() {
        OwnerDto ownerDto = new OwnerDto();
        ownerDto.setId(this.getId());
        ownerDto.setName(this.getName());
        ownerDto.setVersion(this.getVersion());
        if (this.getCars() != null) ownerDto.setCars(this.getCars().stream().map(Car::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        return ownerDto;
    }
}
```

and my Car class is as follow :

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String licenseNo;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @JoinColumn( name = "owner_id" )
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Owner owner;
    @Override
    public CarDto convertToDto() {
        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();
        carDto.setId(this.getId());
        carDto.setLicenseNo(this.getLicenseNo());
        carDto.setVersion(this.getVersion());
        return carDto;
    }
}
```

OwnerService :

```
@Service
public class OwnerServiceImpl implements OwnerService {

    @Autowired
    OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Owner> findAll() {
        return ownerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

OwnerController :

```
@RestController
public class OwnerController {
    @Autowired
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/owners", produces = "application/vnd.demo.api.v1+json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<OwnerDto>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ownerService.findAll().stream().map(Owner::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

cURL :

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/owner \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.demo.api.v1+json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -d '{
    "name": "pranay5"
}'

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/owner/5/car \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.demo.api.v1+json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -d '{
    "licenseNo": "MSH-5555"
}'
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

On a side note: @BatchSize(size = 5) JPA makes only two queries
When I set @BatchSize(size = 5) without making any other changes, it makes only two queries to the database.

```
select o_.id , o_.created_at, o_.updated_at, o_.name from owner o_ 

select c_.owner_id, c_.id, c_.created_at, c_.updated_at, c_.license_no, c_.owner_id, from car c_ where c_.owner_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But my doubt is why FetchType.LAZY making N+1 queries?

Code: https://github.com/pranayhere/exception-demo-mvn

Comment: When do you see this behavior? Are you iterating over the list? Exporting it to JSON/XML? If you only query then it will work, you are probably doing something else that triggers the select.

Comment: I'm fetching the data in ownerService as ownerRepository.findAll(). And convertToDao is iterating over the fetched results. I'm quite sure about not fetching records one by one. Strangely `@BatchSize(size = M)` is working for me, and that makes N/M + 1 queries.

Comment: You don't show where you're consuming this code. Lazy fetching is _expected_ to cause N+1 if you're actually iterating over the values.

Comment: I'm updating the post

Comment: You have 1 query for all entries, and iterate over them to create a dto. IN the dto you access the collection and because it is lazy it needs to issue a select. So actually making the collection lazy introduced the N+1 select issue (1 for all Owners, and 1 for all the cars per owner). Either write a custom query to FETCH JOIN the cars, or make the `cars` property `EAGER` so that it will be joined into the query.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the point of `FetchType.LAZY`. It **is NOT a solution** to `N+1 problem`, but **the cause** of that problem. Simplest (but not optimal) option is to switch to `FetchType.EAGER`. If you don't want to switch you should use Entity Graphs (example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs) or use queries with `FETCH JOIN`  as mentioned above

Comment: yup, you guys are right. DTO query is causing the problem. Is @BatchSize(size = M) appropriate way to solve this?

Comment: No it isn't. As mentioned either make the collection `FetchType.EAGER` or write a custom query for this to `FETCH JOIN` the collection (making it eager for this instance). Messing around with `@BatchSize` isn't going to solve this.

Comment: **JPA: N+1 query even after FetchType.LAZY** - N+1 IS **BECAUSE** OF LAZY

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is that you use the default `findAll` of the `OwnerRepository` and you put `FetchType.LAZY`.

Because you get the cars in the `Owner::convertToDto`, Hibernate has to fetch the cars it did not fetched because of the lazy fetching.

To avoid the additional queries, create a new JPA method in the OwnerRepository getAllBy with an EntityGraph to eagerly fetch the cars in the query:

```
public class OwnerRepository extend JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {
            "cars",
    })
    List<Owners> getAllBy();

}
```

Then use it in your service instead of the findAll.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code and I think the problem is in `OwnerController`:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/owners", produces = "application/vnd.demo.api.v1+json")
public ResponseEntity<List<OwnerDto>> findAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(ownerService.findAll().stream().map(Owner::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

The `Owner.convertToDto()` method iterates over `Owner.cars` field.

Comment: my concern is about the queries to the database. When I set @BatchSize(size = 5) without making any other changes, it makes only two queries to the database

select o_.id , o_.created_at, o_.updated_at, o_.name from owner o_

select c_.owner_id, c_.id, c_.created_at, c_.updated_at, c_.license_no, c_.owner_id, from car c_ where c_.owner_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)   [1,2,3,4,5]